# XLT 1.0 Comparing nodes to a loop

Tags: xslt

I need to copy all nodes and then change one element according to the following conditions.

1. If all nodes **ship** are 0, then replace  = Rejected
2. If all node **qty** are **ship**, then replace  = Accepted
3. If otherwise, then replace  = Changed

No error occurs with 0 values, but if the second option does not work.

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <a>123</a>
    <b>231</b>
    <c>
        <xxx>
            <qty>5</qty>
            <ship>5</ship>
        </xxx>
        <xxx>
            <qty>8</qty>
            <ship>8</ship>
        </xxx>
        <xxx>
            <qty>13</qty>
            <ship>13</ship>
        </xxx>
        <xxx>
            <qty>10</qty>
            <ship>10</ship>
        </xxx>
    </c>
</root>
```

**My XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="/root/a">
        <a>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="not(/root/c/xxx/ship != '0')">Rejected</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="not(/root/c/xxx/ship != /root/c/xxx/qty)">Accepted</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>Changed</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </a>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**UPD**.
I begged xml, because I didn't think that the result would be through predicates
Now the structure of the input file is like this and I already use predicates

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <a>123</a>
    <b>231</b>
    <c>
        <xxx>
            <yyy>
                <what>1</what>
                <qty>5</qty>
            </yyy>
            <yyy>
                <what>2</what>
                <qty>5</qty>
            </yyy>
        </xxx>
        <xxx>
            <yyy>
                <what>1</what>
                <qty>24</qty>
            </yyy>
            <yyy>
                <what>2</what>
                <qty>24</qty>
            </yyy>
        </xxx>
...
    </c>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you want `<xsl:when test="not(/root/c/xxx[ship != qty])">Accepted</xsl:when>`.