# Comparison within a loop XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I have xml in which there is a loop. I want to compare data inside a loop and get the status, but the current xslt is not working. How do I compare the data inside each item and get the status I want? Why isn't my XSLT working?

**Input XML**

```
    <root>
    <a>123</a>
    <b>231</b>
    <c>
        <xxx>
            <qty>5</qty>
            <yyy>
                <ship>5</ship>
            </yyy>
        </xxx>
        <xxx>
            <qty>8</qty>
            <yyy>
                <ship>8</ship>
            </yyy>
        </xxx>
        <xxx>
            <qty>13</qty>
            <yyy>
                <ship>13</ship>
            </yyy>
        </xxx>
        <xxx>
            <qty>10</qty>
            <yyy>
                <ship>10</ship>
            </yyy>
        </xxx>
    </c>
</root>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <a>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="./c/xxx/qty != ./c/xxx/yyy/ship">Changed</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="./c/xxx/qty = ./c/xxx/yyy/ship">Accepted</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>Rejected</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </a>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: In your sample, there are no `./c/xxx/ship` nodes. Can you precise you question?

Comment: How is this question different from your previous one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65207062/xlt-1-0-comparing-nodes-to-a-loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mention of a "loop" is confusing. There is no "loop" in your stylesheet - and no loop is necessary to accomplish your stated purpose of:

> I need to get the general status of a file. If at least one of the  counts is not equal to yyy / ship, then we output the status = Changed, if everywhere is equal, then = Accepted

You can do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <a>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="c/xxx[qty != yyy/ship]">Changed</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>Accepted</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </a>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I need!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming some kind of variation of your question, you could use this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <a>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
        </a>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="c/xxx[qty!=yyy/ship]">Changed</xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="c/xxx[qty =yyy/ship]">Accepted</xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="c[not(xxx)]">Rejected</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This stylesheet assumes that instead of a `<qty>` element there is a `<ship>` element.
And if there was no `xxx` element, you'd get the `REJECTED` output.

Comment: I need to get the general status of a file. If at least one of the <xxx> counts is not equal to yyy / ship, then we output the status = Changed, if everywhere is equal, then = Accepted